# django modelAdmin displayed title

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new to django. I have the following codes:

model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

My profile model contains only some personal fields like full_name, gender, birthdate, etc.

admin:

```
class MyUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyUser
    exclude = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'plan', 'password')
    fieldsets = (
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('email',)}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )


class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = MyUser

    def clean_password(self):
        return ""

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MyUserInline,)
    change_user_password_template = None
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm
    ordering = ('myuser__email',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.myuser.username = obj.myuser.email
        obj.save()

    list_display = ('full_name', 'myuser_email', 'myuser_is_staff', 'myuser_is_superuser', 'myuser_is_active')

    def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=''):
    if not self.has_change_permission(request):
        raise PermissionDenied
    user = self.get_object(request, unquote(id))
    if user is None:
        raise Http404(_('%(name)s object with primary key %(key)r does not exist.') % {
            'name': force_text(self.model._meta.verbose_name),
            'key': escape(id),
        })
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = self.change_password_form(user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # rest of method

    # other minor methods
```

The problems are:

1. In recent actions or after editing a user, I see Profile Object instead of username or email.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVx4a.png)
2. see here: [my other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462317/django-admin-change-user-password)
3. In profile edit page, the permission part contains only a box containing a list of all possible permissions, however there must be another box containing user current permissions list

What it looks like now: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSAav.png)

What it must look like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2pgb.png)

tnx

---

***Update***

for my second problem (change password), I added following lines to `Profile` model:

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    self.myuser.password = make_password(raw_password)
    self.myuser._password = raw_password
```

while debugging, `raw_password` is correctly what I have inserted in the form, and after moving from first line, `self.myuser.password` has new value, but the new value is not submitted into DB.

Comment: (1) implement a sensical `__str__` for the mode; (2) you should add a `set_password` function that hashes and stores the password.

Comment: Nevertheless if the only thing you add is a profile, you probably better do it in reverse: add a one-to-one field that refers to `User` in `Profile`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did what you said, would you mind checking my post update? tnx

Comment: Please only ask a single question at a time [ask]. Your two questions are not really related except that they both are about the django admin. If you are happy with the answer you got to part 1, you should accept that answer, edit your post and remove part 2. Then you can submit that part as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point 1**
Define a `__unicode__` or `__str__` (according to your python version) method in your `Profile` model that returns what you want to display.

**Point 3**
You can add the following line to your `ProfileAdmin`:

```
filter_horizontal = ['user_permissions']
```

to produce a nice two columns filtering field as displayed in your image. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal).

You can also directly use the widget `FilteredSelectMultiple` from `django.contrib.admin.widgets`

Comment: `filter_horizontal = ['user_permissions']` says `The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' refers to 'user_permissions', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.Profile'.`. Using `myuser__user_permissions` does not solve it. user_permissions are defined in `myUser` superclass's superclass (`PermissionsMixin`)

Comment: Ok, maybe look where the permissions widget is defined, maybe in `UserChangeForm` so you might be able to overwrite it in `MyUserChangeForm`

Comment: That was great, both of your answers worked, tnx. `filter_horizontal = ['user_permissions']` was added in `MyUserInline`. Do you have any idea about second issue?